# Javscript vanila click event works on computer, but not on phone

Tags: javascript

https://codepen.io/allanrivers/pen/NWNKWwL

When I click on the correct answer it works correctly on my computer. When I do the same on mobile it doesn't work correctly. I tried using the touchstart, but that caused the whole app to not function correctly. ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```js
const questions = document.querySelectorAll('.questions');
const question1 = document.querySelector('.question1');



const question = () => {
//   loop through all the answers in order to add click event
for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  questions[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    
//     If the answer is correct
    if(questions[i].innerText === 'Of course'){
      questions[0].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      let h1 = document.createElement('h1');
      h1.innerText = 'Correct!'
      question1.appendChild(h1);
      
      // let btn = document.createElement('button');
      // btn.innerHTML = 'Next question';
      // question1.appendChild(btn);
      
      
//       Reset btn
//       let reset = document.createElement('button');
//       reset.innerHTML = 'Reset';
//       question1.appendChild(reset);
//       reset.addEventListener('click', () => history.go(0))
      
      

//       Remove the wrong answers
      for(let i = 1; i <= questions.length; i++) {
        questions[i].remove()
      }
      
      
    } else {
//      Grab the current answer and change the color to red
     let changeColor = e.target;
     changeColor.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
     
//       Create an h1 to indicate that user has chosen the wrong answer
      let wrongh1 = document.createElement('h1'); 
      wrongh1.innerText = 'I\'m sorry, but that\'s incorrect. Try again!';
      wrongh1.classList.add('wrong');
      question1.appendChild(wrongh1);
      
//       setTimeout to delete the extra h1 tags
      setTimeout(() => {wrongh1.remove()}, 1500)
    }
  }, {once: true})
}
}

question()
```

```css
.question1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#title {
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#question {
  color: #333;
}

.question {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;

}

.questions {
  background-color: teal;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="question1">
  <h1 id="title">Quiz</h1>
  <h1 id="question">Is web development fun?</h1>
  <div class="question">
    <div class="questions">
      <h1>Of course</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="questions">
      <h1>No</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="questions">
      <h1>What is web development?</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="questions">
      <h1>Food is better</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `for(let i = 1; i <= questions.length; i++) {
        questions[i].remove();
      }` should be `for(let i = 1,l=questions.length; i<l; i++) {
        questions[i].remove();
      }` but design could be better. It will be in time. Notice your loop tested for a `<=` not `<`. This was also a problem on desktop. Clear your cache.

Comment: Thank you for that, I've been trying to fix that bug.

Answer (score 2):

On my iPhone it looks like the text is followed by lots of trailing spaces, try a simple trim

```
if(questions[i].innerText.trim(' ') === 'Of course')
```